# Set maximum number of processes started by incrond

Tags: files, python, inotify

I am using `incrond` to monitor a directory for incoming files. After each file arrives in the directory a python script is called to process it.

A problem arises when the rate of incoming files is faster than the rate the files are processed. Under these conditions, the system is overwhelmed and the outcome is uncertain.

Is there a way to set the maximum number of processes that the `incrond` is allowed to start? Can another tool be used to queue the processing of the files, so they are processed in a controlled way?

Answer (score 1):

You should not have `incrond` start more processing processes than make sense to run in parallel, e.g. as determined by your number of CPUs or your memory. This is the number N referenced to, in the following text.

The processing processes should only be started by `incrond` and proceed to process files in the "in" directory until nothing is left. If multiple of these processes run, there is some coordination needed so that two processes don't try to process the same task.

If the python scripts can only be run with one file as argument, have `incrond` start a wrapper script that does continue spawning the original python script  as long as there are new files to process, otherwise it exists. This wrapper script is started by `icrond` if there are less than N running at the same time. The wrapper scripts keep processing as long as the incoming rate of files is greater, but they will not miss anything nor slow down the system unnecessarily through too many  parallel scripts running.
Once the incoming rate gets below the processing rate, the number of files that still need processing will reduce to finally end up at zero, and all wrapper scripts exiting.

If there is no easy way to distinguish files that have just arrived from already processed ones,  then have `incrond` write out some to-do task file in a directory, from which the to-do files get processed.

Comment: Thank you. You say 'The wrapper scripts keep processing', but how will it know which files to process? That is the reason why I created the python script, so I can pass the specific filename that I need to process it.

Comment: @Demetris Any file that is still in the input directory (and not moved or deleted) still has to be processed. And if you cannot delete or move the input files, just follow the instructions in the last paragraph of my answer. You can sometimes compare your output directory with your input directory (if not too many files). And in case your processing program writes the output back into the input you're probably doing something wrong as that would again trigger `incrond`

Comment: Thank you for your help. Reading files directly from the directory might lead me into processing files that are still being written to. That is part of the reason I am using `incrond` to make sure that a file has completely arrived to the destination directory before being processed. So, if I have my python script polling the directory, it kind of defeats the purpose.

Comment: That's why I proposed to-do task files that get deleted as an alternative, although I personally prefer to keep an "in" and an "out" directory in order never to have to think about not knowing which files have been processed. Think about what would happen if the machine reboots while it is still processing a number of files. If you split in and out directories what still needs to be done is crystal clear.

Answer (score 0):

Just send your python script command using task-spooler, they will get queued and processed sequentially.
https://www.ostechnix.com/add-linux-commands-queue-execute-one-one/

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. However, pleas avoid postings answers consisting mainly or only of externally linked content, as they can become invalid if the link changes or the site it points to disappears. Instead, add a summary of the key points of the external page (possible with instructions on how to apply it to the question asked) and rather use the link as a "further reading" resource.